# Выход календаря без лишнего всплывающего окна

Tags: html, jquery

Помогите со следующей задачей.

У меня работает так, когда я нажимаю на поле letterDate то выскакивает календарь и поверх него уже ранее занесенные даты и нельзя проматывать годы и месяцы.

Как можно сделать чтобы не выскакивало ранее занесенные даты, получается нужно запретить ввод с клавиатуры?  Т.е. только выбор даты.

HTML

```
<input id="letterDate" name="letterDate" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
```

.

```
$(function() {
        $("#letterDate").datepicker({dateFormat:'dd.mm.yy'});
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно выключить [autocomplete](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/autocomplete)

```
<input id="letterDate" name="letterDate" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker" autocomplete="off">
```

Или можно стандартным способом, просто в `type` указать вместо text - date

Comment: Получается так. Его можно записать в функцию?

Comment: `$('#letterDate').attr('autocomplete','off');`

Comment: Вставил после моей записи, действительно отключает autocomplete. Спасибо. Выбор года и месяца возможно?

Comment: У Вас нельзя выбрать год и месяц? С `datepicker` не работал, если было нужно поле с датой, всегда использовал `type=date`

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо